# Cannot get to the resources under webroot folder

Tags: php, lithium

So i downloaded the source zip for the framework and lithium just now.
I unpacked the lithium zip into the correct directory(all this is on a windows machine) and then used filezilla to upload to my host as a test.

The lithium page shows up fine, but it's not styled.

The folder structure is

- /sample/app
- /sample/libraries/lithium/{lithium core extracted here}.

I didn't make any changes to the files at all.

Replicated the problem in development environment.

Error in firebug is:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/sample/css/debug.css"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a hint that path rewriting is not working. Do you use Apache? If so, you need to enable mod_rewrite

on my server, this is the right command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```

You can also check out my installation instructions for my browser game based on lithium up until to the Chapter "Creating a user" its pretty generic Lithium setup

https://github.com/BitAlchemists/Elenears-Erben/wiki/Installation

Comment: um i dont know exactly what you did =) but you can write an answer yourself and accept it

Comment: basically the .htaccess from the app root didn't make it to the production server. As a result, even if you have mod_rewrite on, it doesn't know its supposed to rewrite anything.

Comment: what did you do with the .htaccess file?
I just downloaded the lithium framework but the css files are not loading. Ive had a similar problem before, and think it was something in the .htaccess files that needed to be changed..